# How to define a UIView from a swiftUI View

Tags: swiftui, uiview, uikit

I need to adapt some sdk demo code from swift to swiftui .
In this code, an element must be created based on a UIView container defined in the storyboard

Setup idea: self.arViewContainer.frame

arViewContainer is non other than the main area of the phone in the storyboard .
I would like to know what to do in swiftui in order to have this setup based on my mainView

Comment: Use `UIViewRepresentable`

Comment: Thanx but this is a bit short

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `UIViewRepresentable` struct, write in the typealias what UIView you need to adapt to, and then implement 2 methods which take in the typealias you provided (and then you can delete the typealias because you don't need it anymore, it's only for Xcode to understand what goes into the 2 methods):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UvzXGP5seEA

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).